# XSLT 1.0 GROUPING like for-each-group in XLST 2.0

Tags: xslt, grouping, xslt-1.0

I have a xml input what i would like to translate to a text. I already solved that this problem with XSLT 2.0 (with for-each-group), but unfortunately ,the application which uses the XSL file, can handle the 1.0 version and i have no idea how i can solve with 1.0.

Thank you!

XML:

```
    <packages>
        <length>50</length>
        <width>50</width>
        <height>50</height>
        <grossWeight>2.1</grossWeight>
    </packages>
        <packages>
        <length>50</length>
        <width>50</width>
        <height>50</height>
        <grossWeight>2.1</grossWeight>
    </packages>
```

Expected output:

```
"packages": [
        {
            "length":50,
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "grossWeight":2.1
        },
        {
            "length":50,
            "width":50,
            "height":50,
            "grossWeight":2.1
        }
    ],
```

Comment: I don't see any grouping required here.

Comment: I don't see any grouping required either but if you have XSLT 2 code you want to transcribe to XSLT 1 then it doesn't hurt including it in the question.

Comment: If you do need grouping in XSLT 1.0, then read up on the "Muenchian grouping" technique, which is convoluted but efficient.